# how to submit the single form and use two submit button one button click then validate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="formSubmit" value="SAVE FOR NOW" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submitAndConfirm" id="submitAndConfirm" value="CONFIRM AND UPLOAD TO SERVER" />
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addPat').submit();
    $('#submitAndConfirm').click(function(){
        $('#addPat').validate({
            rules:{

                iscosId:{required:true},
                pat_id:{required:true},
                admissionDate:{required:true},

                dischargePlace:{required:true}

            },messages:{
                iscosId:"Please reload the Page",
                pat_id:"This field cannot be empty",
                admissionDate:"This field cannot be empty",

                dischargePlace:"This field cannot be empty"

            }
        });
    });
});
```

What I want is; when I submit the `formSubmit` button I want form to not validate, but when I click submitAndConfirm button I want validate the form to be validated.

Comment: You don't explain what the problem is that you're having? Does your code work? does it generate any errors?

Comment: As a side note, never set name attribute to any element inside form to `submit`. This overrides native DOM method: `form.submit()`

Comment: just change the type of first button to "button" and add a onclick function to validate the form. On validation true only, then enable the other submit button to submit the form?

Comment: change both input type submit to "button". On "SAVE FOR NOW" submit form using jquery and on "CONFIRM AND UPLOAD TO SERVER" click validate form and then submit using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
...
});
</script>
```

Anyway, I would check it with php.

```
<?php 
if (isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($_POST['submit'] == "SAVE FOR NOW") {
    //Your PHP testing & action code
  } else { //or elseif ($_POST['submit'] == "CONFIRM AND UPLOAD TO SERVER"
    //Your PHP code 
  };
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if I have completely understood the problem.

when you want a form to be saved by a button and to be submitted by a another button, you have to use the attribute "formnovalidate" at the end of the buttton as bellow:

```
<form action="" method="get" novalidate>
    <p><label for="Text1" >First Name: </label><input name="Text1" type="text" required></p>
    <p><label for="Text2">Last Name: </label><input name="Text2" type="text"></p>
    <p><label for="Text3">Favorite Color: </label><input name="Text3" type="text"></p>
    <p><input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit">&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input name="Save" type="button" value="save" formnovalidate>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: but if i had click confirm button validation is workig after i click save button that time why my form is validate

Comment: if you want your form doesn't validate anything, you can erase the second button. But if you want to let a button save your information, you have to delete the 'novalidate' attribute on the 'form'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#formSubmit').click(function(){
    $('#addPat').submit();
});


$('#submitAndConfirm').click(function(){
$('#addPat').validate({
    rules:{

        iscosId:{required:true},
        pat_id:{required:true},
        admissionDate:{required:true},
        dischargePlace:{required:true}

    },messages:{
        iscosId:"Please reload the Page",
        pat_id:"This field cannot be empty",
        admissionDate:"This field cannot be empty",

        dischargePlace:"This field cannot be empty"

    }
});
});

});
```